# Changing HTML table structure based on screen dimensions

Tags: html, css, html-table

Suppose I have a `3x2` HMTL table:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td> <div id="content1"></div> </td>
    <td> <div id="content2"></div> </td>
    <td> <div id="content3"></div> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <div id="content4"></div> </td>
    <td> <div id="content5"></div> </td>
    <td> <div id="content6"></div> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

This is fine when the screen is in landscape mode (ie - `width > height`)

Suppose `height > width`, is there a way of **dynamically** changing the table to the following `2x3` table:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td> <div id="content1"></div> </td>
    <td> <div id="content2"></div> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <div id="content3"></div> </td>
    <td> <div id="content4"></div> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <div id="content5"></div> </td>
    <td> <div id="content6"></div> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: If you change the tags from `table, td, tr` to `div` yes, you can make it responsive. If not, your layout if fixed (`table`)

Comment: Use media query and add css for different device / resolution

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Do you mean creating divs and specifying screen width and height percentages for each?

Comment: If you change the tags to divs, you can use the css `display: table` to accomplish  the same, and when you need to make a responsive breakpoint you can change the display. However, I like it better if don't use tables.

Comment: Maybe, [this](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) article will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
 <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
 <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
 <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
 <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
</tr>
```

```
table {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

tr {
 flex:1 0 300px;
 display:inline;
}

td {
 display:inline-block;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmckay/02tvkyj8/

http://autoprefixer.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to see the table in dynamic way i.e. this technique is called responsive UI, you can specify the width in percentage to each td element but I will not recommend it.

I advice you to stop using tables, tables are very difficult to maintain, rather use div,span, ul, li with css magic to create a table structure and use bootstrap for responsive UI.

You can read more about this here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with jQuery where I am getting all td and then introduicing then into a `tr` that we append at the end of the body.

And after I am displaying `none` or `table` depending the width.

### DEMO

```js
var tbodyTr = $('table td');
var i = 0;

/** Create new lines for height > width **/
tbodyTr.each(function(){

  /* Appending a tr every 2 td */
  if(i%2 == 0){
    $('tbody > tr:last').after('<tr class="wShorterH"></tr>');
  }
  $('tbody > tr:last').append('<td></td>');

  $('tbody > tr:last > td:last').append($(this).html());

  i++;
});

/* Trigger 1st change, maybe the window already below 500 */
WidthChange();

/* when window on resize */
$(window).resize(function(){
    WidthChange();
});

function WidthChange() {
  if($(window).height() > $(window).width()){
    $('tr').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('wShorterH')){
        $(this).addClass('d-table');
        $(this).removeClass('d-none');
      }else{
        $(this).addClass('d-none');
        $(this).removeClass('d-table');
      }
    });
  }else{
    $('tr').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('wShorterH')){
        $(this).removeClass('d-table');
        $(this).addClass('d-none');
      }else{
        $(this).addClass('d-table');
        $(this).removeClass('d-none');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.d-table{
  display: table;
}
.d-none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <div id="content1">1</div> </td>
      <td> <div id="content2">2</div> </td>
      <td> <div id="content3">3</div> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <div id="content4">4</div> </td>
      <td> <div id="content5">5</div> </td>
      <td> <div id="content6">6</div> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```